# Java for loop gets skipped - my mistake?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have already some c# knowledge but I'm really confused by such an easy thing, but maybe the problem is deeper than I expect. I imported a "little game" for learning java and wrote that code:

```
import de.ur.mi.bouncer.apps.BouncerApp;

public class DasErsteHindernis extends BouncerApp {

@Override
public void bounce() {
    loadMap("Obstacles");
    runtillwall();
    climbupwards();

}

private void runtillwall(){
    while(bouncer.canMoveForward() == true){
        bouncer.move();
    }
}
private void climbupwards(){
    bouncer.turnLeft();
    bouncer.move();
    for(int i = 0; i==2; i++){
        bouncer.turnLeft();
    }




}
```

But the for loop gets skipped -> the bouncer doesn't turn left. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you think `for(int i = 0; i==2; i++)` does?

Comment: Well... `i==2` is clearly false. Do you mean `i < 2`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It runs the loop 2x so the method gets called twice. So after every time the loop runs i gets i+1 until i equals 2.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: This might be helpful, especially the "termination" explanation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann `for (a; b; c) { d; }` is equivalent to `a; while (b) { d; c; }`

Comment: Yeah I thought the loop runs until the condition i==2 equals true. My false thank you everyone

Answer (score 2):

The middle part of a for loop is a condition. Yours is saying while i is equal to 2, do this. It never gets to two, so it never executes. You should be using the less-than or less-than-or-equal-to sign. (<  <=)

Comment: Oh now i got it it should be  i!=2 or <=. @user3376587

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i==2; i++){
```

Here you are initializing `i` with 0,so first when loop starts `i` is 0 ,then middle part which is condition in your loop that should be true for loop to start.In your case,you are saying if `i` is equal to 2 then execute the instruction.It fails and your loop body is not executed single time.

it seems you need

```
 for(int i = 0; i<=2; i++){
```

This one will execute loop body 3 times.

### See Also

- [for loop in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)